# Random/ Loop challenge

Tags: python-3.x

Thanks in advance for your answer(s). So, I just started learning Python, and was faced with a challenge that now is mind bugging. Here is the challenge:

> > > Objective was to write a program that simulates a fortune cookie. The program should display one of five unique fortunes, at random, each time it's runs.
> > >
> > > My solution:

```
# Program simulates fortune cookie.
# Displays one of five unique fortunes at random

"""
Fortunes:
* You will meet someone that will change your life today.
* Invest in lottery this week because you will win big.
* You will get a call from someone with great influence this week.
* Purchase chinese food as you will read a fortune that will come to pass.
* Good news about an inheritance will come shortly.
"""

# Steps:

# Display a Welcome message explaining what the Fortune cookie program is  about, and how users can use it.
# Import random module to randomize the messages.
# Employ loop to repeat.

#Welcome

print("\t\t\n<<<Welcome to Your Fortune Cookie.>>>")
print("\t*To see what the Fortune Cookie Ginie has in store for you.")
print("\t*Ok, here we go...\n")


print(input("Press Enter to Reveal your Fortune: "))

#random module
import random
fortune1 = random.randint(1, 6)

#loop body

fortune1 < 1
while True:
print("You will meet someone that will change your life today.")
print(input(">>Press Enter again to Reveal another Fortune: "))
if fortune1 == 2:
    print("Fortune: Invest in lottery this week because you will win big.")
    print(input(">>Press Enter again to Reveal another Fortune: "))
elif fortune1 == 3:
    print("Fortune: You will get a call from someone of great influence    this week.")
    print(input(">>Press Enter again to Reveal another Fortune: "))
elif fortune1 == 4:
    print("Fortune: Purchase chinese food as you will read a fortune that will come to pass.")
    print(input(">>Press Enter again to Reveal another Fortune: "))
elif fortune1 == 4:
    print("Fortune: Good news! An inheritance will come shortly.")
    print(input(">>Press Enter again to Reveal another Fortune: "))
elif fortune1 == 5:
    print("Fortune: Aha! You will win something this weekend")
    print(input(">>Press Enter again to Reveal another Fortune: "))
else:
    print("Let's check again...")
fortune1 += 1
print("That's all your fortune")
```

> > > Although I want to run it differently, but the program sort of ran. I guess my question is: is there another way i could've done this? Thanks again for your responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to do it is have a list of the outputs, then randomly choose one output from the list with `random.choice(list)`. Example:

```
import random

fortunes = ['fortune1', 'fortune2', 'fortune3']

while True:
    input("Press enter to receive a fortune. ")
    print(random.choice(fortunes))
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I wanted :)